# gwt-function call with java script

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

sorry, I know the question has been asked in the past, but I don't get it to run. Can anyone tell me, why my code isn't working?

What I try is: I want to call a gwt function with java script in a html page. The gwt function creates an int, returns it and javascript should parse it in the html page.

My java code is:

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

public class TestCode implements EntryPoint {
  public static native void exportTestReturn()/*-{
    $wnd.testReturn = $entry(@com.test.client.TestCode::testReturn());
  }-*/;

  public static int testReturn(){
    int testVar = 3;
    return testVar;
  }

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    exportTestReturn();
  }
}
```

And my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>TestTitle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.test.TestCode/com.test.TestCode.nocache.js">
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <p>Gwt html file tries to start gwt function and parse the return value</p>
    <script>
      document.write("JS output:" + testReturn() + "<br>");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are calling the function before it has been exported by GWT `onModuleload`.

GWT uses a bootstrap script (your_app.nocache.js) which computes the permutation and then loads the application script (xxxx.cache.js) asynchronously.

If you call your function from the javascript console of your browse, you can see that it works.

Configure your javascript code to wait until the GWT code has been fully loaded, or put it in a function block and call it from your JSNI method.

```
public static native void exportTestReturn()/*-{
  $wnd.testReturn = $entry(@com.test.client.TestCode::testReturn());
  $wnd.onLoad();
}-*/;


<script>
  function onLoad() {
    document.write("JS output:" + testReturn() + "<br>");
  }
</script>
```

If you prefer wait until gwt has been loaded, enter in a loop until any of the var which gwt sets in the window object when it is loaded exists, this is a pretty much tricky solution though:

```
<script>
 (function loopWaitGwtReady() {          
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (window.__gwt_activeModules)
       document.write("JS output:" + testReturn() + "<br>");
    else
       loopWaitGwtReady()
  }, 50)
 })();    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it's not working for me. If I add the `$wnd.onLoad();` and put the document line in a function like you told me, I get following error: 

`[ERROR] [com.test.TestCode] Unable to load module entry point class com.test.client.TestCode (see associated exception for details)
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.test.client.TestCode::exportTestReturn()([]): $wnd.onLoad is not a function`

Comment: There is a minor typo in the answer - it should be `function onLoad() {`, not `onLoad() {`. Making this change will correctly declare the function so that it can be called from in GWT code.

Comment: Thanks, thats working :-)
How would the other solution be implemented? How can I make my javascript code wait till the gwt code is completely loaded?

Comment: Edited my response with a loop waiting to gwt being available

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find time to test your code until today. So are you sure your second example is correct? Why is the whole function in brackets () ?

Comment: replace `__gwt_activeModules` by `window.__gwt_activeModules`